# how to edit value in json?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm using axios , on response I'm getting json file. As I know axios converts json file to object by default. Here is how it looks:

```
let newMessage{
      channel:"WHATSAPP",
      messages:"[{"message_type":"text","message_content":"call me back"}]",
      position_id:0,
    }
```

But "messages" is a string, it supposed to be an array. So I json.parse messages , getting "message_content" and assigning to a value . But value does not change. What could be the problem?

```
JSON.parse(newMessage.messages)[0].message_content = "xoxo"
```

Comment: You should change the JSON so it is stored as an array instead of a string if you have control over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the original string does not change because your code is altering the object which was produced by the JSON.parse() function, not the original string. You'd have to stringify that value back again and then overwrite the "messages" property of the object with the new string:

```js
let newMessage = {
  channel: "WHATSAPP",
  messages: '[{"message_type ":"text ","message_content ":"call me back "}]',
  position_id: 0,
};

var messageArr = JSON.parse(newMessage.messages);
messageArr[0].message_content = "xoxo";
newMessage.messages = JSON.stringify(messageArr);
console.log(newMessage);
```

P.S. The code in your question did not compile, so I took the liberty of altering it to what I assumed you intended.

Answer (score 0):

```
let newMessage = {
  channel: "WHATSAPP",
  messages: '[{"message_type ":"text ","message_content ":"call me back "}]',
  position_id: 0,
};

let newmessageArr = JSON.parse(newMessage.messages);

newmessageArr[0].message_content = "xoxo";
newMessage.messages = JSON.stringify(newmessageArr);
console.log(newMessage);
```

Comment: Please add here some description of what have you changed in the code or where the mistake was.